# Is it possible to create widgets within the build method by using for loops?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a non scrollable grid that in it's whole expands to it's parent. I am trying to run a for loop in the build method to create the rows and columns. But I get the following errors

```
The element type 'Set<Row>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.
```

and

```
The element type 'Set<Text>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.
```

from the for loop. Why is this? And how can I fix this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpandingGridArguments{
  List<Widget> tiles;
  int columns;
  int rows;
  ExpandingGridArguments(List<Widget> tiles, int columns)
  {
    this.tiles = tiles;
    this.columns = columns;
    this.rows = (tiles.length / columns).ceil();
  }
}

class StaticGrid extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final ExpandingGridArguments arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Column(
      children: 
      [
        for(int c = 0; c < arguments.rows; c++ )
        {
          Row
          (
            children : 
            [
              for(int r = 0; r < arguments.columns; r++)
              {
                Text('A row'),
              }
            ]
          ),
        }
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of `for` inside lists is slightly different from what you did.

Instead of:

```dart
[
  for (var i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
    Text('$i')
  }
]
```

it is used without the `{}`:

```dart
[
  for (var i = 0; i < 42; i++)
    Text('$i')
]
```

The reason for this being that `{}` is also used to create `Set`/`Map`:

```dart
Set<int> hashSet = {};
```

As such, using `{}` inside lists for readability is not supported, because Dart would confuse a "block" with the creation of a `Set`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function outside the build method to do the for loop and return the widgets

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpandingGridArguments{
  List<Widget> tiles;
  int columns;
  int rows;
  ExpandingGridArguments(List<Widget> tiles, int columns)
  {
    this.tiles = tiles;
    this.columns = columns;
    this.rows = (tiles.length / columns).ceil();
  }
}

class StaticGrid extends StatelessWidget {

  buildRows(ExpandingGridArguments arguments) {
     List<Widget> row = new List();
     for(int c = 0; c < arguments.rows; c++ )
        {
          row.add(
            Row
            (
              children : 
              [
                for(int r = 0; r < arguments.columns; r++)
                {
                  Text('A row'),
                }
              ]
            )
          )
       }
    return row;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final ExpandingGridArguments arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Column(
      children: buildRows(arguments)
    );
  }
}
```

Personally, I find it a lot cleaner.

The reason for your errors is because `for` loops are done differently inside the build method. What you are doing is creating a `Set`